# Advice for testing services which require usage of DbQuery<T> - Entity Framework Core 2.1 - InMemory

Tags: entity-framework-core

Can anyone offer any advice on a decent way to set test data against a DbQuery property on a DbContext.

In my application I have a DbQuery mapped to a sql view.

All of the DbSet properties are great for testing with InMemory database as I can create, delete etc.

How can I set values to be returned from a DbQuery, best I can think of so far is Sub classing my DbContext to override OnModelCreating but I imagine there must be a better way?

Comment: I've asked for clarification as well.  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/948